# Get the element itself which cause the event in jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have buttons like this

```
<button class="btn methodDeleteBtn" name="1"  value="Delete"></button>
<button class="btn methodDeleteBtn" name="2"  value="Delete"></button>
<button class="btn methodDeleteBtn" name="3"  value="Delete"></button>
<button class="btn methodDeleteBtn" name="4"  value="Delete"></button>
```

and I get the click event here.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".methodDeleteBtn").click(function(){
        console.log("delete:"); // How to get the "name" value????  
        }
     )
});
```

If I can get the element itself like this I get the value of name.

```
   $(".methodDeleteBtn").click(function(e){
        e.name // If I can get the element itself.
   }
```

Does anyone know the good way to solve this?

Comment: `this.name` or `e.target.name`

Comment: Why not pass in the `event` like in your second example?

Comment: you can use `this` inside callback to select current clicked element `$(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` which refers to the item triggering the event.

You should also be using the [newer syntax](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like this.

```
$(".methodDeleteBtn").on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('name)); 
});
```

Please not that if you plan on using `$(this)` many times, you should store it in a variable to speed things up.

Like this example:

```
$(".methodDeleteBtn").on('click', function(){
    vat t = $(this);
    console.log(t.attr('name));
    console.log(t.val());
    //etc.
});
```

Comment: Thanks! it is very simple and neat.

Answer (score 0):

You can get name value by this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".methodDeleteBtn").click(function(){
       var name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
       alert(name);
    }
 )
});
```